# How do I add more controls after createPartControl?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm making a property sheet via `org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed`, and I have a section where I need to dynamically generate the fields in the properties section based on what element is selected. The problem is that I do not know the selected element before `createControls`, and I cannot change it so that I do know it. How can I dynamically add fields to the composite?

I'm using the WindowBuilder tool to more easily create other parts of the form, though I don't need to use it.

Here is an example which shows what I'm trying to do:

**Form.java**

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;

public class Form extends Composite {

    private final FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(Display.getCurrent());
    private Text text;

    /**
     * Create the composite.
     * @param parent
     * @param style
     */
    public Form(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
                toolkit.dispose();
            }
        });
        toolkit.adapt(this);
        toolkit.paintBordersFor(this);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        Label lblNewLabel = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        toolkit.adapt(lblNewLabel, true, true);
        lblNewLabel.setText("New Label");

        text = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        toolkit.adapt(text, true, true);

    }

    public void addDataToForm(String label) {
        Label lblNewLabel = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        toolkit.adapt(lblNewLabel, true, true);
        lblNewLabel.setText(label);

        // Don't just want to add Texts; sometimes a checkbox, sometimes something else entirely
        Text text = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        toolkit.adapt(text, true, true);
    }
}
```

**PropertySection.java**

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.AbstractPropertySection;
import org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.TabbedPropertySheetPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.TabbedPropertySheetWidgetFactory;

public class PropertySection extends AbstractPropertySection {
    private Form form;

    @Override
    public void createControls(Composite parent, TabbedPropertySheetPage aTabbedPropertySheetPage) {
        super.createControls(parent, aTabbedPropertySheetPage);

        TabbedPropertySheetWidgetFactory factory = getWidgetFactory();
        Composite composite = factory.createFlatFormComposite(parent);

        form = new Form(composite, SWT.NONE);
        FormData data = new FormData();
        data.left = new FormAttachment(0);
        data.right = new FormAttachment(100);
        form.setLayoutData(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh() {
        // This is where I am able to obtain the info I need to add the elements to the form
        // This doesn't work:
        form.addDataToForm("My Label");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `layout(true, true)` in `addDataToForm` to get the `Composite` to redo its layout taking the new contents in to account.